# Changing the format of a column of Data frame from Str to Date in specific format

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, merge

I have two data frames which I have to merge on Date.
but the type of data isn't same. They are Date and of str format.

```
print(visit_data.iloc[0]['visit_date'])
2016-05-22

type(visit_data.iloc[0]['visit_date'])
Out[40]: datetime.date

print(holiday_data.iloc[0]['visit_date'])
1/1/2016

type(holiday_data.iloc[0]['visit_date'])
Out[46]: str
```

So this are type and formats. Now I am using this to merge.

```
    data_store = pd.merge(data_store, holiday_data, how = 'left' , on = ['visit_date','State']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Merge is happening as there are 2 keys but data is not coming in output which is probably due to different format of visit_date.
So, I tried to change that by this.

```
holiday_data['visit_date'] = pd.to_datetime(holiday_data['visit_date'], format = 'format="%m/%d/%Y')
```

but this gives

```
print(holiday_data.iloc[0]['visit_date'])
2016-01-01 00:00:00

type(holiday_data.iloc[0]['visit_date'])
Out[54]: pandas.tslib.Timestamp
```

Which is not what I want.

I am changing the data type of `holiday_data` because length of `data_store` is very long.So any help on this to resolve the issue? I am using python2.7

Comment: Shouldn't it be `%d/%m/%Y` ?

Comment: @NickilMaveli `format = '%Y-%m-%d'` is my desired format because the format of `visit_data['visit_date'] ` is So.

Comment: The `format` param is to help `to_datetime` to determine the args, how it's displayed is completely separate operation, for that you can use `dt.strftime` but this returns a string not a datetime

Comment: @EdChum I misunderstood the function, I have the edited the question now , Please have a look.

Comment: Why is the format of the display important here? You want to keep the data as datetime dtype for arithmetic operations, if you want a different format you can then call `dt.strftime('"%m/%d/%Y')` to add a new string column with your desired format

Comment: @EdChum There is NO data in the merged dataframe across the columns of holiday_data. So I am guessing having different format of `visit_date` may be the reason and second `datetime.strftime` changes  datetime into string, I want the opposite for whole column Which is what I am trying to do by `holiday_data['visit_date'] = pd.to_datetime(holiday_data['visit_date'], format = 'format="%m/%d/%Y')
` but not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to return as a `datetime` object, you could do this:

```
import datetime 

holiday_data['visit_date'] = holiday_data['visit_date'].apply(lambda x: 
                                    datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%m/%d/%Y'))
```

**EDIT :**

To retrieve just the date from the datetime object, use the [`dt accessor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor).

Working example:

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(['1/1/2016', '1/2/2016', '1/3/2016', '1/4/2016', '1/5/2016'], columns=['Mycol'])

In [3]: df['Mycol'] = df['Mycol'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%m/%d/%Y')).dt.date

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
        Mycol
0  2016-01-01
1  2016-01-02
2  2016-01-03
3  2016-01-04
4  2016-01-05

In [5]: df.iloc[0]['Mycol']
Out[5]: datetime.date(2016, 1, 1)

In [6]: type(df.iloc[0]['Mycol'])
Out[6]: datetime.date
```

Comment: I did the same and I have written the output in question only.

Comment: already tried the same `holiday_data['visit_date'] = holiday_data['visit_date'].apply(lambda x: 
                                    datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%m/%d/%Y'))
    

type(holiday_data.iloc[65]['visit_date'])
Out[72]: pandas.tslib.Timestamp

print(holiday_data.iloc[65]['visit_date'])
2016-01-02 00:00:00` still the same output

Comment: Why not try the updated answer and see if you indeed get what you are after?

Comment: Are you sure it worked? because for me it giving me error, `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'datetime'`

Comment: Oops. Maybe because I had imported `datetime` as `dt` and also used `dt` accessor. Hence that error. I've corrected it.